# In any python API documentation, why are optional arguments written in a nested style?

Tags: python, optional-parameters

It's just, why do this:

```
find([spec=None[, fields=None[, skip=0[, limit=0[, timeout=True[, snapshot=False[, tailable=False[, sort=None[, max_scan=None[, as_class=None[, slave_okay=False[, await_data=False[, partial=False[, manipulate=True[, read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY[, exhaust=False[, compile_re=True[, **kwargs]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]])
```

Which seems ugly and confusing, yet appears in every api docs I've ever come across, I may lack some basic python knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I do not have any authentic source to back my statement**

Optional positional arguments presented in a nested style would enforce the proper ordering of the fields.

For Example in [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module for [fdopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdopen)

```
os.fdopen(fd[, mode[, bufsize]])
```

Indicates that mode and bufsize are optional but if you are specifying bufsize you should also specify mode.

For Keywords argument, on the other hand, a default value is specified without any order enforcement to inndicate that the value is optional in which case, the parameter would be initialized with the default value

For example in [re] module for [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.split)

```
split(string, maxsplit=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a convention borrowed from [extended Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). As pointed out above by Abhijit, the nesting means optional to the optional argument etc.