# python optional argument to optional argument validation

Tags: python

In python, how to validate optional-to-optional keyword arguments?

this question is an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950651/in-any-python-api-documentation-why-are-optional-arguments-written-in-a-nested) of mine about this optional-to-optional-arguments thing, (does it have a better name by the way?)

we know we can define optional arguments in this style:

```py
os.fdopen(fd[, mode[, bufsize]])
```

so that if I mistakenly call `fdopen` by `fdopen(sth, bufsize=16)`, python  will point out I must specify `mode` to use `bufsize` argument.

**How is this implemented?** I can obviously write so much if-elseses to make this work, but that would result in some really messed-up code for those really complicated functions, for example:

```py
cv2.dilate(src, kernel[, dst[, anchor[, iterations[, borderType[, borderValue]]]]]) → dst
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017996/python-optional-parameter

There's no actual 'optional to optional' in python, there's just optional. The other semantics are implemented by the function itself. Since python provides lots of programmatic ways to get the arglist, named arguments, etc, this can be programmed reasonably generically, without necessarily resorting to a million ifs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017996/python-optional-parameter

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific syntax for this at Python level. You have to define ordinary optional arguments and do the validation yourself.

---

The specific case you're looking at is implemented in C. Depending on which platform you're on, the C implementation is different. [Here's the version for POSIX, Windows, and OS/2:](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l6879)

```
static PyObject *
posix_fdopen(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    ...
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i|si", &fd, &orgmode, &bufsize))
        return NULL;
```

The use of `PyArg_ParseTuple` means that this function doesn't actually accept any arguments by name. If you do `os.fdopen(sth, bufsize=16)`, you'll get a TypeError:

```
>>> os.fdopen('', bufsize=16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fdopen() takes no keyword arguments
```

---

Note that there's no real reason the `bufsize` argument should depend on the `mode` argument. I think this function probably predates keyword arguments, though it's hard to be sure. Keyword arguments were added to Python [all the way back in 1.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20080114002214/http://www.amk.ca/python/writing/12-14), and the earliest Python documentation available on python.org is for [1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/), by which time [`os.fdopen` was definitely around](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node74.html#SECTION00910000000000000000).